# Get the latlong of 8 points in javascript around a marker in Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get the lat long of 8 locations at a distance of x meters around a marker placed on google maps. Please refer to the image to get an idea.

[image: Please see the image to get an idea]

Basically I want to get an Array of 8 Locations(N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW)  arounds the placed marker. These points can be of x meter from the marker.

[image]

Comment: Do you know the angle(heading)? or only the distance?

Comment: @stack-learner its only the distance. And all the six points are at the edge of a circle.

Comment: circle has an infinite number of points, which points would they be placed on a circle? Your data is incomplete.

Comment: Circles DONT HAVE EDGES

Comment: Related question: [Draw ring (not circle) in Google Maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397874/draw-ring-not-circle-in-google-maps-api)

Comment: Related question: [google maps circle to polyline coordinate array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664685/google-maps-circle-to-polyline-coordinate-array)

Comment: Please check the updated question

Comment: @geocodezip I have updated the question. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Start by asking a correct question... You say you want to find **6** points but you list **7** (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W) where obviously **8** would make a bit more sense (?). So what do you want??

Comment: @MrUpsidown yup Actually 8 points.

Comment: What problems are you having creating that array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the [geometry library computeOffset method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) to compute positions at the desired distance from the center point every 45 degrees:

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var centerPt = map.getCenter();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: centerPt,
    map: map
  })
  for (var angle = 0, i = 0; angle < 360; angle += 45, i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(centerPt, 100, angle),
      map: map,
      title: "marker #" + i + ", at " + angle + " degrees"
    })
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```