# How to calculate coordinate map

Tags: google-maps

I'll create polygon coordinate on google map,

but i dont know how to get coordinate from degree

`360/5 = 72` and I get degree `[0,72,144,216,288,360,0]` to draw polygon

how to getting cordinate from center.

example center coordinate `lat: -6.213689, lng: 106.560494` and `radius: 1km`

expectation

```
/**
0deg => longitude: ? , latitude: ?
72deg => longitude: ? , latitude: ?
144deg => longitude: ? , latitude: ?
216deg => longitude: ? , latitude: ?
288deg => longitude: ? , latitude: ?
360deg => longitude: ? , latitude: ?
**/
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps circle to polyline coordinate array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664685/google-maps-circle-to-polyline-coordinate-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Trigonometrical circle

[image]

You have done well so far, you will need to acquire some theoretical knowledge going forward. Don't worry, it's not difficult. Let's first understand what a trigonometrical circle is.

The trigonometrical circle is a circle in the OXY plane, whose center is located on O(0, 0) and radius is equal to 1.

## Points on the trigonometrical circle

[image]

From the figure you can see that a point located at a given degree, let's say, it's 72 degree (0.0174533 radians). The coordinates of P, where A is the degree are **(cos(A), sin(A))**. If A = 72, then the coordinates are **(cos(72), sin(72)) = (0.99984769502, 0.0174533)**

## How to compute it

In many cases, degrees are calculated in radians. You might have to convert degrees into radians in order to get the correct result.

## Scaling

If the radius is not 1, but r, then the coordinates on the trigonometric circle are **(r * cos(A), r * sin(A))**

## Translation

If your polygon is not centered on O(0, 0), but C(Xc, Yc), then the formula modifies to **(Xc + r * cos(A), Yc + r * sin(A))**